# Rodapé não fica fixo no fim da tela

Tags: css

Criei um página onde terá um rodapé que deverá ficar fixado no final da página, quando a pagina é iniciada ela tem determinado tamanho no total e o rodapé funciona normalmente no começo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém possuo nessa mesma página um botão que exibe um container que inicialmente vem como *Hiden*, porém ao clicar esse botão e o container passar a ser exibido o rodapé não fica mais no final da página corretamente, ele acaba ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBSERVAÇÃO:** O rodapé seria a linha azul no caso

Meu CSS está assim:

```
.myCSS{
    background-color: #036;  
    font-size: 14px;
    float:left;                 
    color: #FFF;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 5px;

}
```

há algum modo de manter o rodapé fixo no fim da tela independente da página aumentar o tamanho?

Comment: Edite e coloque o HTML junto por favor.

Comment: Resolvi o problema, é que ele estava fora do container principal, por esse motivo os dados novos acabavam sobrepondo ele, mas obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Show, eu tinha feito o código. Talvez outra pessoa precise no futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve utilizar `position:absolute;` no seu footer e definir `right:0;bottom:0;left:0;` para que ele fique na parte de baixo da página.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.demo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
}

.demo h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}


.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <h1>Exemplo</h1>

  <p>Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto </p>

    <p>Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto </p>
    
      <p>Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto </p>
      
</div>

<div class="footer">Exemplo de footer <strong>absolute</strong>.</div>
```

Comment: Pode [edit] a resposta e adicionar a explicação de como ele funciona?

Comment: Claro. Farei isso agora mesmo.